# ¿Esta este codigo bien optimizado?

Tags: php, wordpress, funciones

El siguiente código e para un tema Genesis para Wordpress llamado AgentPress Pro, a este tema se le instala un plugin llamado AgentPress Listing, funciona con un Post Type. el PostType por defecto no tiene habilitado los meta info que tiene un post por defecto, es decir no aparece la parte donde dice, Publicado por, nombre del autor.
Navegando encontré este código que inserta un autor box en los post, lo modifique para que solo funcione en el posttype, quite codigo extra como el avatar y descripción, y ahora se muestra como la imagen que muestro a continuación con enlace a el archivo del autor, aunque logre lo que queria, me pregunto si el codigo es limpio y bien optimizado[image: Imagen que muestra lo que aparece al pie de cada Post Type]

```
    <?php

//Author Listing Archive

function listing_author_link( $content ) {

global $post;

// the code will be added only for listings
if ( is_singular( 'listing' ) && isset( $post->post_author ) ) {

// Get author's display name 
$display_name = get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', $post->post_author );

// If display name is not available then use nickname as display name
if ( empty( $display_name ) )
$display_name = get_the_author_meta( 'nickname', $post->post_author );

// Get link to the author archive page
$user_posts = get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' , $post->post_author));

if ( ! empty( $display_name ) )

$author_details = '<span><b>Productora u Organizador</b></span>';

if ( ! empty( $user_description ) )

$author_details .= '<p class="author_details">' . nl2br( $user_description ). '</p>';

$author_details .= '<p class="author_links"><a href="'. $user_posts .'">' . $display_name . '</a>';    

// Pass all this info to post content  
$content = $content . '<footer class="property-details-col2 one-half" >' . $author_details . '</footer>';
}
return $content;
}

// Add our function to the post content filter 
add_action( 'the_content', 'listing_author_link' );

// Allow HTML in author bio section 
remove_filter('pre_user_description', 'wp_filter_kses');
?>
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Esta pregunta se podria considerar basada en opiniones.. que seria limpio y bien optimizado?

Comment: La variable que se evalúa aquí `if ( ! empty( $user_description ) )`  no existe en el contexto.

Comment: una posible optimización es crear un [transient](https://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API) cuya key sea  `'author_info_' . $post->post_author` y el value sea el html generado, asi te ahorrás pegarle a la db en cada `the_content` con todos los if

Comment: Hola @A.Cedano , esta variable que indicas , la he eliminado y todo funciona bien , Mucha Gracias

Comment: @aloMalbarez no entendí qué quisiste decir con esto:  *asi te ahorrás pegarle a la db en cada the_content con todos los if*  ... ni por qué sugieres lo del transient ¿?  Creo que este código no inserta nada a la BD.

Comment: Serían estas dos líneas las que sobran: `if ( ! empty( $user_description ) )

$author_details .= '<p class="author_details">' . nl2br( $user_description ). '</p>';` por el hecho de que en ese contexto no hay una variable llamada `$user_description`

Comment: @A.Cedano cada get meta lee desde el object cache o desde la db, con un transient lees un solo valor y no varios `display_name`, `nickname`, posts url + post meta `ID` etc, salvo que se estén creando y borrando authors a un ritmo muy alto es conveniente guardar el html calculado y listo para renderizar en un transient con un lifetime acorde a los cambios en los authors

Comment: Hola @A.Cedano he eliminado ya las 2 lineas que incas y todo bien , Muchas Gracias

Comment: @aloMalbarez eso ya son palabras mayores para mí, ni siquiera sabía que eso funcionaba así.

Comment: Hola @aloMalbarez en relidad soy aficionado, no conozco mucho mas lo que he aprendido a prueba y error, comprendo muy poco lo que indicas , lo que entiendo es que lo que sugieres aliviana la consultas a la base de datos, y por ende acelera la carga del la pagina ...es asi ?

Comment: es uno de los niveles de cache de wordpress, si ves que hay cosas que no cambian mucho en la representación pero implican muchas consultas (en la db) a datos que no cambian mucho y varios if tal cosa entonces tal otra, ahí entran los transients. Si carga mas rápido la página dependerá de cuando expiran los transients y que otros niveles de cache tengas activados, por lo general te ahorra ciclos de cpu y memoria que dependiendo del plan de hosting pueden hacer una diferencia en momentos de alto tráfico.

Comment: Ok @aloMalbarez quite algunos if y la ultima linea que indica habilitar html en la descripción

Comment: Así quedaría el código según lo indicado [ https://github.com/klish09/author-archive-link/blob/master/listing-author-link.php ]